# how to get updated value after ajax removes data from within it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, live, bind

I have a an element with thumbnails.  I allow users to sort their display order (which fires off an update to the DB via ajax).  I also allow them to delete images (which, after deletion, fires off a request to update the display order for all remaining images).

My problem is with binding or live I think, but I don't know where to apply it.

The array fired off upon delete contains ALL the ids for the images that were there on page load.  The issue is that after they delete an image the array STILL contains the original ids (including the one that was deleted) so it is obviously not refreshing the value of the element after ajax has removed things from inside it. I need to tell it to go get the refreshed contents...

From what I have been reading, this is normal but I don't understand how to tie it into my routine.  I need to trigger the mass re-ordering after any deletion.

Any ideas gurus?

```
    $('a.delimg').click(function(){
 var parent = $(this).parent().parent(); 
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../updateImages.php",
    data: "action=delete&id=" + id,
    beforeSend: function() {
  parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);

  $.jnotify("<strong>Deleting This Image & Updating The Image Order</strong>", 5000);
  },
    success: function(data) {
  parent.slideUp(300,function() {
   parent.remove();

  $("#images ul").sortable(function() { //NEEDS TO GET THE UPDATED CONTENT
  var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings';
  $.post("../updateImages.php", order, function(theResponse){
  $.jnotify("<strong>" + theResponse + "</strong>", 2000);
  });
     });
       });

      }
    });
    return false;
    });
```

Thanks for any help you can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess would be that the items are cached by the plugin. You could test this by calling examining the items like so:

```
var items = $("#images ul").sortable( "option", "items" );
```

If this does not contain the updated list of items you can set them again

```
$("#images ul").sortable( "option", "items", 'li' );
```

This check would go in your function before the line where you have the comment

```
//NEEDS TO GET THE UPDATED CONTENT
```

---

Instead of trying to re-set the items, how about [destroying](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-destroy) the sortable and reinitializing.

```
$("#images ul").sortable("destroy"); // destroy
$("#images ul").sortable(); // init
```

Comment: sorry to be dense, but do I use that example literally?  For example, .selector is not valid on my page and what are the option, items, li reference...  Usually, the sortable plugin requires my to run a function on update or some other event, but I am just trying to pass the array without any further user activity...  maybe this is the problem?  Maybe the question should be about the sortable plugin

Comment: @brian - i updated the selector. Assuming you are using `li` in your `ul` the rest should be fine.

Comment: It does not give an error, but seems be making no difference.  When I try to see the value of 'items' using an alert it simply shows it as an object.
 

Sorry to be so 'new'.  I don't understand what the 'option' and 'items' reference are for.. I don't have them in my original jquery sortable syntax. I am not sure how they factor in here or how they get it to get a new value from the #images ul (which contains li tags around the images with ids)

Comment: ok.. i found the reference in sortable library... so I don't think it is getting the items after the update...  any ideas?

Comment: I generally use chrome/firebug for js debugging. You can hover on variables and see the data (in an alert it simply shows object.toString() -> [object]) You can use the debugger keyword to break in your developer toolbar also. See my updated solution... (coming)

Comment: For the benefit of others, JQUERY sortable does not cache the data, I had an error in my JS logic.  Once i fixed that, I simply asked for the contents of the div after altering its contents and it serialized the new contents properly, without using the refresh method...